# Camera zoom setting using Camera2 API

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I'm trying to use the new Camera2 API to access camera setting and apply a zoom.
In old deprecated Camera API, the code was like follows:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
parameters.setZoom(zoomValue);
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

How can we achieve the same, considering that CameraManager
 is used to open the camera?

```
CameraManager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, backgroundHandler);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the next code. Call **setZoom** with your target [CaptureRequest.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.Builder), so the preview or picture tacking builder whenever is needed.

Use **maxZoom** to get the threshold at which your UI should compute the zoom range.
The zoom range will be always between **DEFAULT_ZOOM_FACTOR** and **maxZoom**.

After calling **setZoom**, to make the new zoom active you still need to send it to the current [CameraCaptureSession](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession) with a **Repeating Request**.

Snippet to compute a new zoom factor:

```
public final class Zoom
{
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM_FACTOR = 1.0f;

    @NonNull
    private final Rect mCropRegion = new Rect();

    public final float maxZoom;

    @Nullable
    private final Rect mSensorSize;

    public final boolean hasSupport;

    public Zoom(@NonNull final CameraCharacteristics characteristics)
    {
        this.mSensorSize = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_ACTIVE_ARRAY_SIZE);

        if (this.mSensorSize == null)
        {
            this.maxZoom = Zoom.DEFAULT_ZOOM_FACTOR;
            this.hasSupport = false;
            return;
        }

        final Float value = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM);

        this.maxZoom = ((value == null) || (value < Zoom.DEFAULT_ZOOM_FACTOR))
                ? Zoom.DEFAULT_ZOOM_FACTOR
                : value;

        this.hasSupport = (Float.compare(this.maxZoom, Zoom.DEFAULT_ZOOM_FACTOR) > 0);
    }

    public void setZoom(@NonNull final CaptureRequest.Builder builder, final float zoom)
    {
        if (this.hasSupport == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        final float newZoom = MathUtils.clamp(zoom, Zoom.DEFAULT_ZOOM_FACTOR, this.maxZoom);

        final int centerX = this.mSensorSize.width() / 2;
        final int centerY = this.mSensorSize.height() / 2;
        final int deltaX  = (int)((0.5f * this.mSensorSize.width()) / newZoom);
        final int deltaY  = (int)((0.5f * this.mSensorSize.height()) / newZoom);

        this.mCropRegion.set(centerX - deltaX,
                centerY - deltaY,
                centerX + deltaX,
                centerY + deltaY);

        builder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, this.mCropRegion);
    }
}
```

Snippet to apply the new computed zoom:

```
yourCameraSession.setRepeatingRequest(builder.build(), yourPreviewOrCaptureSessionCallback, yourCameraThreadHandler);
```

Comment: Thats great but if I understand this correctly,there isnt a direct way to do access the zoom specs on the camera and change it without manipulation of the view .

Comment: For camera2 the paradigm is different, this is not a view manipulation but the direct way to change the zoom. In the old API, setZoom was just an easy to use method which internally probably was doing something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Are you sure that `characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_AVAILABLE_MAX_DIGITAL_ZOOM)` can be null? Documentation doesn't have such info, so I don't think it can be null...

Comment: @user25, The characteristics.get method return value is Nullable, check the source code. So, regardless if a specific request can or not return null, you have two options: 1) check for nullability, 2) Or, add lint ignore statements to stop the null lint warning. Is up to you. If you can live with null warnings then don't need to check for null in this specific flag.

Answer (score 3):

Since PerraCollabs@ already mentioned how to use the api, I will try to explain the paradigm shift.

In the camera1 API, zoom is a simple center crop zoom, which is something like this:
[image]

Like you can see the api is simply cropping into the center of the frame and scaling the resultant to the screen. This is how Android has defined the application and vendor HAL APIs. The vendor HAL will simply get the zoom level and calculate the crop values itself while the android framework simply passes the zoom  value to camera HAL.

In Camera2 api this is more flexible in the sense that you can crop any part of the frame and then scale. So essentially using camera2 api something like is possible:
[image]

Observe how the inner rectangle is not centered. This couldn't be done using the camera1 api.

Though this is a nice flexibility for the app developers, I think android could've provided a camera1 equivalent key as well for straight forward use cases in the camera2 CaptureRequest.